# Firefox twitching issue with transform rotate

Tags: javascript

I have made an analogue clock which rotates using javascript function in chrome and IE it works nicely, to my eye at least, but in firefox the minute hand twitches for reason not known to me I am posting .js file and .html file because I reckon that the .css file is not relevant.

**JS:**

```
var hourHand = document.getElementById('hourHand');
var minuteHand = document.getElementById('minuteHand');

function initClock(){
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours() % 12;
var minute = date.getMinutes();
var second = date.getSeconds();

var hourDeg =  (hour * 30) + (0.5 * minute);
var minuteDeg = (minute * 6) + (0.1 * second);

hourHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + hourDeg + 'deg)';
minuteHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + minuteDeg + 'deg)';


setTimeout(initClock, 1000);
};

initClock();
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div>
        <div class="levo">
            <img id="slikaLevo" src="TIDlevo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="kontejner">
            <div class="clock">
                <img class="hands" src="TidClockFace.png">
                <img id="hourHand" class="hands-cl" src="velika.png">
                <img id="minuteHand" class="hands-cl" src="mala.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="desno">
            <img class="desnoSlika" src="TIDdesno.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am providing a JSFiddle link so You guys can see what I'm talking about:
https://jsfiddle.net/MicroDev92/8j1rteqd/19/

is this something that can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This is because how Firefox smooths transforms, in order to avoid aliasing. It's not something done immediately but after a short delay.

As mentioned in [this article](https://tiffanybbrown.com/2013/04/13/smoothing-jagged-edges-on-transformed-objects-in-firefox/), you can fix this by adding `border: 1px solid transparent` to the object. This will apply aliasing immediately, to avoid having that twitch.

```js
var hourHand = document.getElementById('hourHand');
var minuteHand = document.getElementById('minuteHand');

function initClock(){
 var date = new Date();
 var hour = date.getHours() % 12;
 var minute = date.getMinutes();
 var second = date.getSeconds();
 
 var hourDeg =  (hour * 30) + (0.5 * minute);
 var minuteDeg = (minute * 6) + (0.1 * second);
 
 hourHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + hourDeg + 'deg)';
 minuteHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + minuteDeg + 'deg)';

 
 setTimeout(initClock, 1000);
};

initClock();
```

```css
.levo{
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 27%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
#slikaLevo{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.kontejner{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16.7%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
}
.clock{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;

}
.hands{
 top:0;
 left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
.hands-cl {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.desno {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 52.2%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.desnoSlika{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testiranjeSata.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header-logo">
        <div>
            <div class="levo">
                <img id="slikaLevo" src="https://image.ibb.co/jXRDCT/TIDlevo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="kontejner">
                <div class="clock">
                    <img class="hands" src="https://image.ibb.co/kCnLsT/Tid_Clock_Face.png">
                    <img id="hourHand" class="hands-cl" src="https://image.ibb.co/mKv6XT/velika.png">
                    <img id="minuteHand" class="hands-cl" src="https://image.ibb.co/mCyRXT/mala.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="desno">
                <img class="desnoSlika" src="https://image.ibb.co/bx0Je8/TIDdesno.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't fix it, since the border applies to the whole canvas, rather than to the actual image(the image is smaller than the canvas on which it resides), so the twitch isn't gone? Open the JSFiddle link in firefox and check out the minute hand, it twitches in every point of the rotation :(

Comment: I tested on Firefox and it doesn't twitch. What version are you using?

Comment: It says my current version is 61.0.1 (64-bit)...could that be the problem?

Comment: The code I provided doesn't do the twitch on `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0`